# each() jquery issue adding value multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have following script in jQuery:

```
var cval5 = ' ';
$(':input[value^="ltrDataColumn"]').filter(':checked').each(function (index) {
    var val = (this).value;
    val = val.replace('ltrDataColumn', '');
    cval5 = cval5 + val + '@@';
});
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:370px">
    <option value="ltrDataColumnred">Red</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumngreen">Green</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnblue">Blue</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnorange">Orange</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnpurple">Purple</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnyellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnbrown">Brown</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnblack">Black</option>
</select>
```

In the above list I only select only yellow but the  result is showing `yellow@@yellow@@` instead of `yellow@@`.

It's adding the value twice. I tried a lot but I'm not able to replicate it why it is adding two times each value.

Comment: What exactly is the result you get and what result do you expect?

Comment: its addding val value two tiems

Comment: please share the relevant html also

Comment: Yes, you wrote that in your question. I still would like to see an example of the result you get and the one you want. While I can imagine what you mean by *"It's adding the value twice."*, an example would be helpful.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PYpFy/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny there is no output

Comment: @pavezalam: Open the console. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: There is no error in error console window

Comment: Because it's not an error. The error console is not the place to look at. Read the article I linked to.

Comment: please don't tell me .. you are using `:checked` for select element.. :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a `select` element, you need to use the :selected filter not :checked

```
$('select option[value^="ltrDataColumn"]:selected').each(function (index) {
    var val = this.value;
    val = val.replace('ltrDataColumn', '');
    cval5 = cval5 + val + '@@';
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PYpFy/)

Another way to look at this will be

```
var cval5 = $('select option[value^="ltrDataColumn"]:selected').map(function(){
    return this.value.replace('ltrDataColumn', '');
}).get().join('@@');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jjEGQ/)

Comment: i cannot change the selector, because there are multiple list , i have to find all the inputs start with ltrdatacolumn and checked

Comment: second worked for me, just one problem , its not adding @@ to the last selected value

Comment: @pavezalam do you want output like in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a select element. So, your script should look like that:

```
var cval5 = ' ';
var select = $("select[multiple='multiple']");
var value = select.val();
if(value != null) {
    for(var i=0; val=value[i]; i++) {
        val = val.replace('ltrDataColumn', '');
        cval5 = cval5 + val + '@@';
    }
}
alert(cval5);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/PYpFy/4/

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AhmfX/)

First , you confuse `checked` and `selected` and you don't use the good selectors , Look at the console to see the output , try this :

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:370px">
    <option value="ltrDataColumnred" selected>Red</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumngreen" selected>Green</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnblue">Blue</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnorange" selected>Orange</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnpurple">Purple</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnyellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnbrown">Brown</option>
    <option value="ltrDataColumnblack">Black</option>
 </select>
```

**JS :**

```
var cval5 = ' ';
$('option[value^="ltrDataColumn"]:selected').each(function (index) {
      var val = (this).value;
      val = val.replace('ltrDataColumn', '');
      cval5 = cval5 + val + '@@';
      console.log(cval5);
  });
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
 red@@
 red@@green@@
 red@@green@@orange@@
```